# How to add a delay between 2 text messages being displayed in Tkinter Python?

Tags: python, function, tkinter, sleep

So my aim is to use a single function to show a text message upon a button click. Then there should be a delay and then another text message should be displayed.

The game is a dice game that should show 'Rolling...' upon a button click. And then after a while, it should display a random number.

I tried both .sleep() and .after() and both of them resulted in my program not showing the before delay text. Here's my code:

```
# Imports
import tkinter as tk
from random import randrange
import time

# Global variables
# SIDES is a constant
SIDES = 12

# Functions
def func():
    display["text"] = "Rolling..."
    window.after(2000)
    display["text"] = str(randrange(SIDES) + 1)
    

# Main program loop
window = tk.Tk()

display = tk.Label(window, text="Press the button \nto roll the dice.", width=20, height=3)
button = tk.Button(window, text="Roll", command=func)

display.pack()
button.pack(pady=10)

window.mainloop()
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Side suggestion, `randint(1, SIDES)` is more descriptive than `randrange(SIDES)+1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
window.after(2000, lambda: display.config(text=randrange(SIDES) + 1))
```

instead of the:

```py
window.after(2000)
display["text"] = str(randrange(SIDES) + 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you `sleep` in the function, the tkinter main loop is interrupted and the screen isn't updated. (`window.after()` is just a gloified sleep here). The correct solution is to pass a callback to `after`, which will make it immediately return and call the callback later:

```
def func():
    display["text"] = "Rolling..."
    window.after(2000, lambda: display.__setitem__("text", str(randrange(SIDES) + 1)))
```

(Note that the call to `__setitem__` is a direct one-liner lambda translation. This is not good design.)

Comment: You can use `window.after(2000, setattr, display, "text", randrange(SIDES) + 1)`. `setattr` is a predefined python function and the `.after` method takes any number of arguments and passes them on